# amout of write line instaces vary depending on YVAL variable

Tags: vb.net, variables, console.writeline

I have a mesurement that could be any random value, just for fun well make that 2440mm i need to divde that by the industry standard of 610mm which comes out at 2440 / 610 = 4

Programicaly written NEWVAL = YVAL / STDVAL

NEWVAL (4) gives me refrence to how many instances I want to append a new line in a txt file I know that I want the first line to say 0,0,0 and the second line to say 0,610,0 the third 0,1220,0 the fourth 0,1830,0 and the last 0,2440,0, though this is easily achived with addition how can I automate vb.net to produce a new write line for each each instace of 610 if the YVAL is user defind.

Put in simple terms half would be missing if the YVAL variable  is double in length at 4880mm

Comment: Wouldn't making the length 4880mm make the NEWVAL = 8? How is this half?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
    Dim YVAL = 2440                                     ''Measurement
    Dim STDVAL = 610                                    ''Standard value
    Dim NEWVAL = YVAL \ STDVAL                          ''Force integer division
    For I = 0 To YVAL Step STDVAL                       ''Loop through each item
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("0,{0},0", I))    ''Output
    Next
```